# Rails 4 accessing model attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm learning rails (I'm mostly a java developer), as will be obvious by my question, and am having trouble accessing a method on my model from my rspec test. I'm basically following [this tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial) but applying it to my own project. I'm trying to define graduation_year as a method based on the grade of the student and the current time of the year.  When I instantiate the object and call the method in rails console it works as I'd expect, but when trying to do it in a test I'm getting:

```
undefined method `graduation_year'
```

### student.rb

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :school_id, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :first_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 30 }
  validates :last_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 40 }
  validates :gender, presence: true, inclusion: { :in => %w(m f M F) }
  validates :grade, presence: true, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 1 , less_than_or_equal_to: 12 }

  def graduation_year
    year = Date.today.year + ( 12 - grade )
  end
end
```

### student_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Student do
  before { @student = Student.new(
                        school_id: 3, 
                        first_name: "Michael", 
                        last_name: "Green", 
                        gender: "M", 
                        grade: 6)}

  subject { @student }

  it { should respond_to(:school_id) }
  it { should respond_to(:first_name) }
  it { should respond_to(:last_name) }
  it { should respond_to(:gender) }
  it { should respond_to(:grade) }
  it { should respond_to(:graduation_year) }

  it { should be_valid }

  describe "when school_id is not present" do
    before { @student.school_id = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end
  .
  .
  .  
  describe "when grade is 7 graduation_year should be calculated correctly" do
    before { @student.grade = 7 }
    expect(@student.graduation_year).to eq(Date.today.year+5)
  end
end
```

### Error message

```
~/dev/rails_apps/spec/models/student_spec.rb:96:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>': undefined method `graduation_year' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from ~/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:242:in `module_eval'
from ~/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:242:in `subclass'
from ~/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:228:in `describe'
from ~/dev/rails_apps/spec/models/student_spec.rb:94:in `block in <top (required)>'
from ~/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:242:in `module_eval'
from ~/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:242:in `subclass'
from ~/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:228:in `describe'
from ~/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/dsl.rb:18:in `describe'
from ~/dev/rails_apps/spec/models/student_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from ~/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load'
from ~/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `block in load_spec_files'
from ~/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `each'
from ~/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load_spec_files'
from ~/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
from ~/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
from ~/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

Also, I don't think this is the issue, but I originally had the `graduation_year` as an attribute on the Student table, but removed it and this test is supposed to verify that it is calculated correctly.

I've also tried `puts first_name` in the tests and I get the same undefined method error but on `first_name`. I think I'm just missing something about the way ruby/rails works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expect statement is not wrapped in an 'it' clause.  Try writing

```
describe "when grade is 7" do
  before { @student.grade = 7 }
  it 'calculates the graduation year correctly' do
    expect(@student.graduation_year).to eq(Date.today.year+5)
  end
end
```

As a side note, use of @student in this manner is not idiomatic.  You'd be better off using a let statement defining student.  So instead of your initial before block with Student.new you'd write something like this:

```
let(:student) { Student.new(
                    school_id: 3, 
                    first_name: "Michael", 
                    last_name: "Green", 
                    gender: "M", 
                    grade: 6)}
```

and all of your subsequent references to '@student' would be replaced with 'student'.  That ensures nothing leaks in (or out) of the describe block.

The let statement will memoize the object, and will only instantiate the object if student is referenced in the spec.

Comment: That's perfect.  And thanks for the extra note about using let().

Answer (score 1):

You can't set expectations directly within a `describe` block as is the case with your line:

```
expect(@student.graduation_year).to eq(Date.today.year+5)
```

You didn't say what specific error you were getting (i.e. what object had the undefined method), but `@student` is going to be `nil` at this point since all undefined instance variables are `nil`, so it won't have a `graduation_year` method. If `@student.graduation_year` had been a valid expression, however, you would have gotten an undefined method on the `expect` call.

Comment: Thanks, I added the error message.  I'm obviously still getting my head around testing in rails.